# Redux call is empty

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've some async data from redux store. This is declared in `mapStateToProps`. When I call this in child component it is empty.

*Parent*

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchFlowDiagramData();
} 
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        flowDiagramData: state.appReducer.flowDiagramData
    }   
}
```

*Child*

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Initialize Flow Diagram JSON
  this.flowJson = this.props.flowDiagramData;
  this.state = {};
}

componentDidMount() {
  var data = this.flowJson; // This is empty
}
```

How do I ensure this async call is retrieved properly?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some more of your code, we can't see here, for instance, how your props are mapped.

Comment: Wait for a component update and check, or have a value in the store that signifies if its done loading or not

Comment: Are you able to check the state of the redux store to verify the value you need is not empty there?

Comment: Why do you need to take value from props and put it to a field? You could simply use `this.props.flowDiagramData` in `componentDidMount`. Also keep in mind that `componentDidMount` fires once per component lifecycle. If the property could change you need to use `componentDidUpdate` as well.

Comment: Added some more context

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Just tried directly using props in componentDidMount. Didn't work. How would componentDidUpdate work? Do I replace it with componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

The componentDidMount lifecycle method isn't triggered on component updates.
You say you're fetching the data, so make sure the component is mounted only after the data is available.